# Previous divs with jQuery does not work after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slider

I have two scripts:

1. The first one is image carousel. It uses jQuery slick slider.
2. The second one is an Ajax script that loads contents as page scrolls down.

Here is my code:

```
function slider () {
  var $arrows = $('.arrows');
  var $next = $arrows.children(".slick-next");    
  var $prev = $arrows.children(".slick-prev");

  var slick = $('.your-class').slick({
    appendArrows: $arrows
  });

  $('.slick-next').on('click', function (e) {
    var i = $next.index( this )
    slick.eq(i).slickNext();
  });

  $('.slick-prev').on('click', function (e) {
    var i = $prev.index( this )
    slick.eq(i).slickPrev();
  });
}

$(document).ajaxComplete(slider);
```

Below is the scroll content load with Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function slider () {

    var $arrows = $('.arrows');
    var $next = $arrows.children(".slick-next");    
    var $prev = $arrows.children(".slick-prev");

    var slick = $('.your-class').slick({
      appendArrows: $arrows
    });

    $('.slick-next').on('click', function (e) {
      var i = $next.index( this )
      slick.eq(i).slickNext();
    });

    $('.slick-prev').on('click', function (e) {
      var i = $prev.index( this )
      slick.eq(i).slickPrev();
    });
  }

  $(document).ajaxComplete(slider);

  var flag = 0;

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getdata.php",
    data: {
      'offset': 0,
      'limit': 10
    },

    success: function(data){
      $('.rowmasonry').append(data);
      flag += 10;
    },

  });

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()-500){
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getdata.php",
        data: {
          'offset': flag,
          'limit': 10
        },

        success: function(data){
          $('.rowmasonry').append(data);
          flag += 10;
        },

      });
    }

  });

});
```

The problem is that the first 10 contents that are loaded work properly. However, as I scroll down, and another 10 contents come, the first 10 contents that were loaded do not respond.

How do I bind the image slider to Ajax, so that all contents on the page work with jQuery?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Depends on plugin api...if they have methods to add content use that, or you may need to initialize plugin again in ajax success. Your specific problem is not well explained

Answer (score 0):

You are just appending new elements to DOM. In order to update slick you need to reInit slick carousel or if you are sure about the slide markup then you can use `slickAdd` method provided by plugin.

`$.ajax().done(function(data){
    $('.your-class').slick('slickAdd', data);
});`

ref: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added your code as follows under scroll part. But it still does not work. 
                done: function(data){
                $('.your-class').slick('slickAdd', data);